# Am unable to redirect to previous activity in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-studio

I am not able to redirect the current activity to the main activity in Android Studio. I was trying to insert data of sign-up activity to database sqLite but it is not working.

```
b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String s1 = e1.getText().toString();
            String s2 = e2.getText().toString();
            String s3 = e3.getText().toString();
            String s6 = e6.getText().toString();
            if (s1.equals("") || s2.equals("") || s3.equals("") || s6.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(Second.this, "FILL ALL THE FIELDS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                SQLiteDatabase data = openOrCreateDatabase("db1", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                data.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users1(name varchar,email varchar,password varchar,phone varchar)");
                String s7 = "SELECT * FROM users1 WHERE name='" + s1 + "' and email='" + s2 + "' and password='" + s3 + "'";
                Cursor cursor = data.rawQuery(s7, null);
                if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(Second.this, "already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    data.execSQL("insert into users1 values('" + s1 + "','" + s2 + "','" + s3 + "','" + s6 + "')");
                    Toast.makeText(Second.this, "all field filled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent il = new Intent(Second.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(il);
                    finish();

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

---

Logs as Requested.

```
    04-28 18:09:44.150 26440-26440/com.example.abhinav.datal E/SQLiteLog: (1) table users1 has 3 columns but 4 values were supplied
04-28 18:09:44.150 26440-26440/com.example.abhinav.datal D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-28 18:09:44.151 26440-26440/com.example.abhinav.datal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.abhinav.datal, PID: 26440
                                                                           android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table users1 has 3 columns but 4 values were supplied (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO users1 VALUES('aa','aa','aa','44')
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:896)
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:507)
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1704)
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1635)
                                                                               at com.example.abhinav.datal.Second$1.onClick(Second.java:49)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5269)
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21556)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
04-28 18:09:49.925 26440-26449/com.example.abhinav.datal I/System: FinalizerDaemon: finalize objects = 126
```

Comment: can you share your logs ?

Comment: I have posted the logs in answers, please check.

Answer (score 0):

As logs are suggesting your table `users1` has `3` columns and you are trying to insert `4` values into it.

**Here are scenarios :-**

**1 -** You really want `3` columns and you are inserting `4` elements by mistake.

**2 -** You want `4` columns but your table `users1` has `3` columns and you are writing this query

```
SQLiteDatabase data = openOrCreateDatabase("db1", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                data.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users1(name varchar,email varchar,password varchar,phone varchar)");
```

this query creates four columns table if `users1` does not exist.
If `users1` table exists then it will not create any table.
So, all you have to do is delete your schema that has been created in your device first. For that you will have to **uninstall** the existing application from your device and try **reinstalling** it.

Answer (score 0):

You expect the table to be created using this statement:

```
data.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users1(name varchar,email varchar,password varchar,phone varchar)");
```

The Exception states:

```
[...] table users1 has 3 columns but 4 values were supplied [...]
```

If you previously created the table `user1` with only 3 columns your code wont update it as it checks whether or not the table already exists (`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`).

You could try dropping or altering table `user1`.